Angular event listener updates class properties but not template
New to Angular (using 18.2) and trying to get callbacks from mouse events on an svg working. The code is like this:
component.html
…
  <object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml" #mySvg></object>
…

<div>
  @if (activeElement) { ... display info re svg path ... }
</div>


component.ts
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  protected activeElement: type = undefined

  @ViewChild('mySvg')
  mySvg!: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.mySvg.nativeElement.addEventListener('load', () => {
     this.mySvg.nativeElement.contentDocument.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('mouseover', this.onMouseover.bind(this))
    })
  }

  protected onMouseover(event: MouseEvent): void {
    if (conditions) {
      this.activeElement = this.service.getDataForElement(event.target)
    } else {
      this.activeElement = undefined
    }
  }

The callbacks appear to be working as expected. On mouseover the onMouseover method is called and the class variables are updated (confirmed via console.log(JSON.stringify(this)) at various points in the process) but the template does not respond to the variable changes. I have tried several different versions of ngAfterViewInit such as putting all the logic directly there (instead of binding) and using a timeout as suggested a few places but no change in behavior.
The only way I have been able to get it to work is by changing the template to
…
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" (mouseover)="onMouseover($event)">
    <path...>
    …
  </svg>


So I assume that the controller -> template interactions SHOULD be working.
Any suggestions on how to debug this or what to look into? Thanks in advance.

It's strange that an element's load event would fire in any of the component's lifecycle events. I think that it's "too late" to be in the code. In the template however it's simple html and behaves like any "out of Angular" markup. I'm saying it because I tried it myself and load never fired in the code.

@BennyHalperin you have also tried with getter and setter as explained in my answer?

The change detector mechanism is probably the problem here. So your class variable activeElement must add to the Angular change detector mechanism, that the changes be tracked and has effect to the template file.
Add setter and getter for your class variable activeElement. This would track the changes, since setters and getters are parts of the change detector.
.ts file:
get activeElementValue() {
    return this.activeElement
}

set activeElementValue(activeElement) {
    this.activeElement = activeElement
}

…

if (conditions) {
    this.activeElementValue = this.service.getDataForElement(event.target);
} else {
    this.activeElementValue = undefined;
}

.html file:
…
<div>
    @if (activeElementValue) { ... display info re svg path ... }
</div>
…


Other opportunities to handle change detector, are setTimeout() or detectChanges(). But with these solutions you interfere with the Angular lifecycle. That's why I recommend solving the problem with getters and setters.
But here are the code examples anyway
setTimeout:
if (conditions) {
    setTimeout(() => this.activeElement = this.service.getDataForElement(event.target));
} else {
    setTineout(() => this.activeElement = undefined);
}

detectChanges:
if (conditions) {
    this.activeElement = this.service.getDataForElement(event.target);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
} else {
    this.activeElement = undefined;
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}


thanks for this. I was able to get it to work using the change detector. The set/get did not seem to change the previous behavior, unfortunately.

@AaronLuman I recommend to update your question and share your fix in it

@AaronLuman I don‘t understand, then the change derector is also a part of my answer. So what did you do differently than in my answer?
